# P-value significance levels in corrplot

Tags: r, plot, correlation, levels, significance

I would like to show not only * when a correlation is significant but the different significance levels, e.g. * for p < .05, ** for p < 0.01 and so on.

I calculated a correlation and the p-value-function as follows:

```
Corr_Emo <- cor(df_Emo[, 3:11], method = "pearson")
pval <- psych::corr.test(df_Emo[3:11], adjust="none")$p
```

and plotted my corrplot

```
corrplot(Corr_Emo, 
         method="color", col=col(200),
         tl.srt = 45,
         tl.cex = 1.0,
         tl.col = "black",
         diag=FALSE, 
         type="upper", #order="hclust", 
         title=title,
         addCoef.col = "black",
         # Combine with significance
         p.mat = pval, sig.level = 0.05, insig="label_sig", pch.cex = 1.5,
         mar=c(0,0,1,0)
)
```

but of course it only signs a correlation * if it is significant in any way.
I am not that good in R so I don't know exactly how to modify pval with psych::corr.test in a way that it shows me the different levels of *.

Could anybody help me here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?